# How to merge array of hash of array of hash on condition?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, merge

Aim is to merge arrays if it has the same value but carry over existing array of hashes that are inside it.

code so far:

```
aff_packages = [{:platform=>"platform 5", :pkg=>"package1", :state=>"somestate"},
                {:platform=>"platform 7", :pkg=>"package2", :state=>"somestate"},
                {:platform=>"platform 5", :pkg=>"package3", :state=>"somestate"},
                {:platform=>"platform 5", :pkg=>"package4", :state=>"somestate"},
                {:platform=>"platform 7", :pkg=>"package5", :state=>"somestate"},
                {:platform=>"platform 6", :pkg=>"package6", :state=>"somestate"
                }]

  aff_packages.each do |package|

    small_array = []
    print_me = big_array = []
    hash = Hash.new
    print_me << hash

    small_array << {
        package: package[:pkg],
        state:  package[:state]
    }

    (hash[package[:platform]] ||= small_array)

    end
```

which produces:

```
[{"platform 5"=>[{:package=>"package1", :state=>"somestate"}]}]
[{"platform 7"=>[{:package=>"package2", :state=>"somestate"}]}]
[{"platform 5"=>[{:package=>"package3", :state=>"somestate"}]}]
[{"platform 5"=>[{:package=>"package4", :state=>"somestate"}]}]
[{"platform 7"=>[{:package=>"package5", :state=>"somestate"}]}]
[{"platform 6"=>[{:package=>"package6", :state=>"somestate"}]}]
```

How can I merge the same platforms together but carry over the array of hashes and append it like so:

```
[{"platform 5"=>[{:package=>"package1", :state=>"somestate"}], [{:package=>"package3", :state=>"somestate"}], [{:package=>"package4", :state=>"somestate"}]}]
[{"platform 7"=>[{:package=>"package2", :state=>"somestate"}], [{:package=>"package5", :state=>"somestate"}]}]
[{"platform 6"=>[{:package=>"package6", :state=>"somestate"}]}]
```

Comment: Your expected result is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible solution.

Input as given by your code:

```
aff_packages = [{:platform=>"platform 5", :pkg=>"package1", :state=>"somestate"},
                {:platform=>"platform 7", :pkg=>"package2", :state=>"somestate"},
                {:platform=>"platform 5", :pkg=>"package3", :state=>"somestate"},
                {:platform=>"platform 5", :pkg=>"package4", :state=>"somestate"},
                {:platform=>"platform 7", :pkg=>"package5", :state=>"somestate"},
                {:platform=>"platform 6", :pkg=>"package6", :state=>"somestate"
                }]
```

---

**Step 1:** Create hash with platform as key and rest of attributes as values hash

```
ary = aff_packages.map do |package|
    # Let's create a copy as we don't want to modify aff_packages
    pkg = package.dup

    # Remove :platform's value from pkg hash
    platform = pkg.delete(:platform)

    # Return platform name and rest of hash as key-value
    { platform => pkg }
end
```

At this point, `ary` is an array of hash as shown below:

```
[{"platform 5"=>{:pkg=>"package1", :state=>"somestate"}}, 
 {"platform 7"=>{:pkg=>"package2", :state=>"somestate"}}, 
 {"platform 5"=>{:pkg=>"package3", :state=>"somestate"}}, 
 {"platform 5"=>{:pkg=>"package4", :state=>"somestate"}}, 
 {"platform 7"=>{:pkg=>"package5", :state=>"somestate"}}, 
 {"platform 6"=>{:pkg=>"package6", :state=>"somestate"}}]
```

---

**Step 2:** We now have array of hashes, let's merge the hashes such that for a given key, the values are collected as array.

```
h = ary.reduce(Hash.new{|hash, k| hash[k] = []}) do |memo, i| 
    memo[i.keys.first] << i.values.first; memo 
end
```

Note that we are using [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) to collect the values in a new `Hash`.  Also, notice the usage of block syntax of [`Hash#new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) which allows to have default value of empty array for each key.

At this point, we have hash `h` whose value is shown below.

```
{"platform 5"=>
  [{:pkg=>"package1", :state=>"somestate"},
   {:pkg=>"package3", :state=>"somestate"},
   {:pkg=>"package4", :state=>"somestate"}],
 "platform 7"=>
  [{:pkg=>"package2", :state=>"somestate"},
   {:pkg=>"package5", :state=>"somestate"}],
 "platform 6"=>[{:pkg=>"package6", :state=>"somestate"}]}
```

Typically, this will be desired output.

---

**Step 3:** It seems that you need output wherein each key-value pair representing a platform lives in its own array.  We need this step to covert hash from Step 2 to desired output.

```
output = h.map {|k,v| [{k => v}]}
```

At this point, `output` value is as shown below:

```
[[{"platform 5"=>
    [{:pkg=>"package1", :state=>"somestate"},
     {:pkg=>"package3", :state=>"somestate"},
     {:pkg=>"package4", :state=>"somestate"}]}],
 [{"platform 7"=>
    [{:pkg=>"package2", :state=>"somestate"},
     {:pkg=>"package5", :state=>"somestate"}]}],
 [{"platform 6"=>[{:pkg=>"package6", :state=>"somestate"}]}]]
```

---

A side-note

To pretty-print Hashes and Arrays, you can use Ruby's [PP class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/pp/rdoc/PP.html). For e.g.

```
require "pp

pp hash_object
```

Comment: Perhaps `each_with_object` rather than `reduce` to get rid of that pesky `; memo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by). Here:

```
aff_packages.group_by { |a| a[:platform] }
# => {"platform 5"=>[{:platform=>"platform 5", :pkg=>"package1", :state=>"somestate"}, {:platform=>"platform 5", :pkg=>"package3", :state=>"somestate"}, {:platform=>"platform 5", :pkg=>"package4", :state=>"somestate"}],
# "platform 7"=>[{:platform=>"platform 7", :pkg=>"package2", :state=>"somestate"}, {:platform=>"platform 7", :pkg=>"package5", :state=>"somestate"}],
# "platform 6"=>[{:platform=>"platform 6", :pkg=>"package6", :state=>"somestate"}]}
```